# How to transform a sentence in present perfect into it-cleft construction?

Tags: cleft-constructions

If I transform a sentence in present perfect into *it*-cleft construction, for example,

> He has inspired me.

which pair of tenses used in both matrix and subordinate clauses are correct? or neither.

> 1. It was he who has inspired me.
> 2. It has been he who has inspired me.

Comment: Either *It **was** he who **[had] inspired** me* or *It **is** he who **has inspired / does inspire / inspires** me*. Don't mix incompatible present and past tense verbs. But in almost all contexts it would be much better to stick with the simpler form *He [has] inspired me*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He has inspired me.

We can change it into a cleft sentence :

> It **is** he who **has inspired** me.

NOT, It **was** he who **has inspired** me.

We cannot mix past and present tenses in matrix and content clauses.

If the sentence is :

> He had inspired me

The cleft sentence should be :

> It was he who had inspired me.